# UPNP "zonetype" field

Tags: networking, upnp, iot

I'm conducting a research on UPnP packets from different devices, and one of the fields I noticed is `device.zoneType`.

`zoneType` contains a number between 1-24.

Do any of you know the explanation of each number?

Here is an example of an actual parsed upnp packet with this field bolded:

```
{
  "root": {
    "@xmlns": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0",
    "specVersion": {
      "major": "1",
      "minor": "0"
    },
    "device": {
      "deviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:ZonePlayer:1",
      "friendlyName": "Sonos Play:1",
      "manufacturer": "Sonos, Inc.",
      "manufacturerURL": "http://www.sonos.com",
      "modelNumber": "S1",
      "modelDescription": "Sonos Play:1",
      "modelName": "Sonos Play:1",
      "modelURL": "http://www.sonos.com/products/zoneplayers/S1",
      "softwareVersion": "54.2-72031",
      "swGen": "1",
      "hardwareVersion": "1.8.3.7-2",
      "serialNum": "",
      "MACAddress": "",
      "UDN": "uuid:RINCON_5CAAFD78335201400",
      "iconList": {
        "icon": {
          "id": "0",
          "mimetype": "image/png",
          "width": "48",
          "height": "48",
          "depth": "24",
          "url": "/img/icon-S1.png"
        }
      },
      "minCompatibleVersion": "53.0-00000",
      "legacyCompatibleVersion": "36.0-00000",
      "apiVersion": "1.16.0",
      "minApiVersion": "1.1.0",
      "displayVersion": "10.6",
      "extraVersion": "OTP:",
      "roomName": "Woonkamer",
      "displayName": "Play:1",
      **"zoneType": "9",**
      "feature1": "0x00000000",
      "feature2": "0x00403336",
      "feature3": "0x0001000e",
      "seriesid": "A101",
      "variant": "1",
      "internalSpeakerSize": "5",
      "bassExtension": "75.000",
      "satGainOffset": "6.000",
      "memory": "128",
      "flash": "64",
      "flashRepartitioned": "0",
      "ampOnTime": "10",
      "retailMode": "0",
      "serviceList": {
        "service": [
          {
            "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AlarmClock:1",
            "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AlarmClock",
            "controlURL": "/AlarmClock/Control",
            "eventSubURL": "/AlarmClock/Event",
            "SCPDURL": "/xml/AlarmClock1.xml"
          },
          {
            "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:DeviceProperties:1",
            "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:DeviceProperties",
            "controlURL": "/DeviceProperties/Control",
            "eventSubURL": "/DeviceProperties/Event",
            "SCPDURL": "/xml/DeviceProperties1.xml"
          },
          {
            "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SystemProperties:1",
            "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SystemProperties",
            "controlURL": "/SystemProperties/Control",
            "eventSubURL": "/SystemProperties/Event",
            "SCPDURL": "/xml/SystemProperties1.xml"
          },
          {
            "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ZoneGroupTopology:1",
            "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ZoneGroupTopology",
            "controlURL": "/ZoneGroupTopology/Control",
            "eventSubURL": "/ZoneGroupTopology/Event",
            "SCPDURL": "/xml/ZoneGroupTopology1.xml"
          },
          {
            "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:GroupManagement:1",
            "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:GroupManagement",
            "controlURL": "/GroupManagement/Control",
            "eventSubURL": "/GroupManagement/Event",
            "SCPDURL": "/xml/GroupManagement1.xml"
          }
        ]
      },
      "deviceList": {
        "device": {
          "deviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1",
          "friendlyName": " - Sonos Play:1 Media Renderer",
          "manufacturer": "Sonos, Inc.",
          "manufacturerURL": "http://www.sonos.com",
          "modelNumber": "S1",
          "modelDescription": "Sonos Play:1 Media Renderer",
          "modelName": "Sonos Play:1",
          "modelURL": "http://www.sonos.com/products/zoneplayers/S1",
          "UDN": "",
          "serviceList": {
            "service": {
              "serviceType": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1",
              "serviceId": "urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl",
              "controlURL": "/MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Control",
              "eventSubURL": "/MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Event",
              "SCPDURL": "/xml/RenderingControl1.xml"
            }
          },
          "iconList": {
            "icon": {
              "mimetype": "image/png",
              "width": "48",
              "height": "48",
              "depth": "24",
              "url": "/img/icon-S1.png"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code so it's not displayed as a single line of code.  Code should be placed in a code, not quote, box so it displays as monospaced; due to the way in which it was copied/pasted into the question, it's not formatted sanely.

Comment: @JW0914 As you wish.